# How to create Xpath to read text between span class?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**HTML:**

```
...<div class="ArticleCount__articleCount___lQ5f1">
<span class="ArticleCount__text___1c2Rn">Showing</span>
9
<span class="ArticleCount__text___1c2Rn">of</span>
23
<span class="ArticleCount__text___1c2Rn">articles</span>
</div>
```

Can you please help me with xpath to get the value 9 and 23; I tried with below options:

```
List<WebElement> list1 = driver.findElements( By.xpath( "//div[starts-
with(@class,'ArticleCount__articleCount')]//span" ) );
     for (int i = 0; 1<list1.size() ; i++)
     {
            System.out.println("Text from String list is::"+list1.get(i).getText());
     }
```

**Output:**

```
Text from String list is :: Showing
Text from String list is :: of
Text from String list is :: articles*
```

Comment: Please share the html DOM, stacktrace and your effort on the problem. This will help us getting to a solution. Your problem statement looks incomplete right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below and let us know the outcome.

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'ArticleCount__articleCount')]
```